# javascript метод который будет находить совпадение определенного элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы, методы

Помогите написать функцию которая будет находить кол-во совпадений определенного элементов в массиве.
Пример:

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 6, 5]
occurencesCount(0) 
occurencesCount(2) 
occurencesCount(3) 
occurencesCount(4) 
occurencesCount(5) 
occurencesCount(6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто можете отфильтровать массив по нужному элементу через метод [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) и получить длину массива.

```js
var arr = [0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6];

occurencesCount(0) // 1
occurencesCount(2) // 1
occurencesCount(3) // 3
occurencesCount(4) // 1
occurencesCount(5) // 1
occurencesCount(6) // 2

function occurencesCount (el) {
  console.log(
    // взять элементы которые совпадают с el
    arr.filter(item => item === el).length
  )
}
```